# Library file not loading in 2.3 but loading in 4.0

Tags: android, android-ndk

My project contains a lib file **libs/armebai/libworkso**  , 
this runs smoothly on a tablet running android 4.0 but when I try to run the same project on 2.3 my project crashes , after commenting out

// System.loadLibrary("work");

in my code the project runs on 2.3 running tablet and crashes only when I call any native functions defined in my project .

**Edit:**

```
08-13 10:54:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1757): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED My problem was solved by compiling/running on a different machine , I don't know how this affects the libworkso file but now it runs on both 2.3 and 4.0 .

*Adding this to close my open question*

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild for all possible CPU/ABI combinations. Android 4 often tries to load `armeabi-v7a` while Android 2.x is happy with `armeabi`.

To do that, create/open Application.mk in the `jni` folder, and place the following:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi x86 armeabi-v7a mips
```

MIPS only if you've got NDK r8.

Comment: but I am not having trouble on 4.0 , I am having troubles with 2.3