# android NDK JNI loadLibrary crashing

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My Android app is crashing when I use

```
static {
    system.LoadLibrary("MySharedLib");
}
```

This is the only noticeable error message I am getting:

> Failed to write stack traces to /data/anr/traces.txt (5571 of 6738): No such file or directory

libMySharedLib.so is generated from ndk-build. I am using powerVR SDK and thus I am assuming that this lib is getting loaded beforehand internally.

I am able to get it working if I separate out my code into a different shared library, but that defeats the purpose of my need (all data, pointers exist in MySharedLib and I want to call the c++ function from Java).

Comment: Open the apk with a zip file tool and verify the .so is present.  Then post the logcat log of the failure

Comment: I had a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003506/library-file-not-loading-in-2-3-but-loading-in-4-0 Strangely trying the following allowed me to run the apk 1)regenerate the apk from a different machine and run on the device you where getting error

Comment: If you are looking to build a separate lib.so file and you use it within your main lib.so then this answer might help with step to follow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Answer (score 0):

The answer is like a needle in a haystack.

Make sure you have all your java JNI_OnLoad, and other functions wrapped in extern "C".
Simple.